# Disk speed test linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive

Is there any simple command (or tool) to test the speed (MB/sec) of disk access?

I've found `hdparm` but It look it only works for local disk. I need to evaluate the speed of remote NFS-mounted disk.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [IOzone](http://www.iozone.org/). Or just time how long it takes to `dd` from your filesystem to `/dev/null`, or from `/dev/zero` to your filesystem.

Comment: It looks the `hdparm` uses `dd` in underlying too. Thanks!